# Indecomposable L-module

Tags: representation-theory, modules, lie-algebras

I have the following exercice which I have be trying to solve:

Let L be a Lie algebra and $r:L\rightarrow gl_3(F)$ a representation of L such that $im(r)=t_3(F)$ (the upper triangular matrices). Show that the L-module associated is indecomposable.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What is $t_3(F)$?

Comment: the upper triangular matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be explicit, the associated $L$-module is $F^3$, and the action of $L$ is the usual action of $t_3(F)$.

*Hint*: Suppose that this $L$-module is decomposable, so that $F^3 = V\oplus W$ for nonzero submodules $V$ and $W$. Then one of these submodules, say $V$, is one-dimensional as an $F$-vector space. Being an $L$-submodule of $F^3$, it must be invariant under the action of $t_3(F)$, as is $W$. Use this information to derive a contradiction.